# How to remove noise from video clip in python programming language?

Tags: python-3.x, data-science, video-processing

```
import noisereduce as nr

img=cv2.imread('rajneeti_audio.mp3',2)

audio_files_noise =cv2.imread(audio_files[0:0:20])

reduced_noise = nr.reduce_noise(audio_clip=img, noise_clip=img, verbose=True)
```

Comment: Hi, I invite you to read following article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, you could state more on the desired output, what's idea and where you got stuck...

Comment: Improved formatting.